# JavaScript convert UTF-8 to base64

Tags: javascript

When I try to run the JS script below get an exception in the code:

```
var encode = window.btoa('Hiroto √')

"@lehesamudi.js:14:26
b.render/<@https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.8.min.js:1:13924
a.use/<@https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.8.min.js:1:10866
"
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you add more details and what exactly you want to do  and also possibly the full error trace?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to escape before, please find the code below.

```
function encode(str) {
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
}

function decode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(str)));
}

// Usage:
encode('Encode me with UTF-8 char: ∑ßåœ ≈ ∆c') // "RW5jb2RlIG1lIHdpdGggVVRGLTggY2hhcjog4oiRw5/DpcWTIOKJiCDiiIZj"
decode("RW5jb2RlIG1lIHdpdGggVVRGLTggY2hhcjog4oiRw5/DpcWTIOKJiCDiiIZj") //'Encode me with UTF-8 char: ∑ßåœ ≈ ∆c'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to encode the character first using the `encodeURI` function because it's not currently in the correct charset range for encoding using btoa.

I.e

`window.btoa(encodeURI('Hiroto √'))` => SGlyb3RvJTIwJUUyJTg4JTlB

To decode:

`decodeURI(window.atob('SGlyb3RvJTIwJUUyJTg4JTlB'))` => Hiroto √